# Can I trust that questions have been closed correctly when reviewing in the reopen queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

I stumbled upon this question in the reopen review queue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205808/loop-in-java-method

In short, it was closed as a duplicate. The edits are only simple grammar and formatting, and nothing that could change the question from a duplicate to a non-duplicate.

Should I just press "Leave closed" or am I expected to check whether it is a duplicate or not? After all, **if** (and only if) it was **correctly** closed as a dup, then I know that it should not be reopened.

(I pressed leave closed without checking)

I guess this question could be generalized too. Sometimes I see questions closed as "too broad", "opinion based" or something else and when I quickly take a look at the differences between the previous and current version I can sometimes easily see that **if** the closing was correct, it should not be reopened.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When reviewing the reopen queue, you're *not* reviewing if the reason the question is in the queue is relevant. You're reviewing if the question should stay closed. The reason it was closed, edits, comments, are mostly irrelevant. The only thing you should do is decide for yourself if the question should be open, or closed.

An exception is questions that are closed for a reason that is actively harmful, e.g. questions that are marked as a duplicate of an unrelated question and will redirect to this question causing confusion. These can be reopened, and then closed again for the correct reason.

This means you should check if it was correctly closed as a duplicate. Even questions that got into the reopen queue for trivial reasons should be adequately reviewed.

Reviewing duplicates is often hard. I recommend you either skip duplicates in languages you're not familiar with, filter out duplicates, or filter the reopen queue to only show languages you're familiar with.

Note that the audits in the reopen queue do test for this. There are audits with trivial edits, where the proper choice is to reopen the question.

Comment: I was about to say that I don't really agree, but if there are audits that tests this specific thing, then I guess the question is settled and that there's nothing more to discuss. Thanks.

Comment: That difficulty, enforced by such audits, makes it less likely that people will be willing to review the reopen queue! It would be much easier to have a reopen reason clearly wrote by the voter instead of hiding it behind a trivial edit: that would at least give a reopen vote equal grounds to a close vote where a reason is mandatory.

Comment: @klutt, People will waste their time if they believe Erik von Asmuth answer: if no reason is immediately visible to re-open, then check if it's an audit. If it's not an audit, "leave closed" until the re-open vote is clarified explicitely.

Comment: Yet, there are numerous questions closed as duplicates that really aren't duplicates of the referenced question. These remain next to impossible to get reopened, particularly if reviewers just assume the close reason was valid.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy [relevant other meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364471/424903) that provides some alternative options.

Comment: @Cœur Possible concern: what happens if a user does significant edit, then another one adds a trivial edit before you get to see the question in review? Is it possible that the important edit gets hidden by the latter?

Comment: @JiriTousek all changes are seen in review (both edits are visually merged for the review).

Comment: @jmarkmurphy always leave a comment: if there is a comment explaining the re-open reason, then it's no more a trivial edit only.

Comment: @Cœur, the review is supposed to be a hard task: we don't want robo-review. You are the judge and we need justice. You have to check evidences, including initial close-reason carefully and only then give your carefully thought verdict.

Comment: This is a good answer. Most importantly, we shouldn't be overly pedantic and do stupid things like "Why was this closed as unclear? It should have been closed as too broad! Cast re-open vote." We need not shovel crap around, there's tons of user moderator work to be done without creating completely pointless tasks for other user moderators.