# How should we handle a wrong duplicate link?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I sometimes see questions marked as duplicate, where the supposed duplicate is not answering the question. For example, [«This keyword in Java, how to use?»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229857) was marked as a duplicate of [«How does the “this” keyword work?»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429) which is tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and not [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). A better duplicate would have been [«When should I use “this” in a class?»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2411270).

Should a moderator handle this? How could I handle it?
Should I comment on the question, or flag it? Can it be ignored?

Comment: You forgot to vote to re-open it.  Meh, we all know why.

Comment: I hate the option to reopen just to close with different reason

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two scenarios:

1. **The question was marked as a duplicate by a gold tag badge holder.**

   Best solution in this case is, in my humble opinion, to [leave a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229857#comment85465120_49229857) and notify the gold tag badge holder of the more appropriate duplicate question. Ask them nicely to consider updating the duplicates list. Nice, effective, doesn't cause a stir.

   [image: Example comment and reply by gold tag badge holder]
2. **The question was marked as a duplicate by 5 voters.**

   In this case, one solution would be to vote to reopen the question, then vote to close it again. This is not nice, to say the least. It also takes a lot of time, has a high likelihood of failing and requires you to be invested and keep an eye on the question.

   It *could* be an option to involve some other members, for example from the [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: Yes, in any case get a gold badge holder involved, to either edit the list or to reopen&reclose. Asking at meta or in chat or, if applicable, in the comments are all valid ways to do so.

Comment: That's so roundabout. I wish it were an option in the reopen queue to vote to fix the dupe link. There's a known problem with people closing as duplicate with completely unrelated links as a mega downvote button. It's frustrating to come across a question that is exactly what you're looking for that's closed as a duplicate of something that is completely unrelated.