# What should I do about wrong duplicate targets used by gold-badge holders?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

In PHP we have two canonicals. One is for [`mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc) API and the other is for [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param) API.
Some gold-badge holders hammer a question using mysqli code with the wrong duplicate. Sometimes another person comes around and edits the duplicate list for the correct one, but it might already be too late. I know that if I saw the wrong duplicate myself I would be very confused about what I should do. This is actively causing harm. The old answers don't explain how to enable MySQLi errors!

I did inform some users about that mistake, but I don't want to be pointing this out to every gold-badge holder. What should I do?

[An example where 2 duplicates where used together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047351/error-warning-mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-b)
[An example where the duplicate list was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58038222/timeline)

Comment: These questions have far, far too many possible duplicates to choose from.  The gold badgers are implicitly trusted to pick the right one, they've seen/answered hundreds of them before.  If you know a better one then just edit it in or copy/paste the link into a comment.

Comment: @hansPassant That is exactly the premise of my question. Why do I have to post the right duplicate in the question every time? Ideally the duplicates should not be mixed up.

Comment: Ideally SO users stop adding more and more duplicates.  Better if you don't encourage them doing that.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention as to which should be the correct duplicate and why. We watch the watchers.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker At least one mod strongly disagrees with you (though I don't know who). Rejection reason (slightly snipped) from last time I did that: *"Moderator flags must not be used to resolve wrong dupe closures. ping the gold badge user ... who closed the question in the comments & inform them the same"*. Something for y'all to figure out amongst yourselves and then present a united front on, I think.

Comment: @MarkAmery you left out a rather important part of the text of your flag that changes the dynamic a bit.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The "..." bit I left out was *"(they were NOT a moderator when they did this)"*. (Readers: the question I was flagging was closed by a moderator, but apparently it was closed prior to them becoming a mod, using their gold badge powers.) George: I don't see why the fact that the closer was a mod would make it *less* appropriate to use a mod flag to contest the dupe target; do you mean to suggest that it does? And in any case, the wording of the decline message is pretty unequivocal that what you're asking us to do is unacceptable in general, not just in the case where I did it.

Comment: @markAmery you left out a bit more than that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker without having seen the message, what exactly do you expect a message like that to contain? That rejection and your reply directly contradict each other.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I've left nothing out; between my two comments here, I've literally quoted the entire rejection reason. Is your issue with the fact that the alternative duplicate target I was suggesting swapping to was one that I had personally answered, and that I flagged that up as I reason I might be "possibly biased" in my flag message? How is that relevant here? You're welcome to disclose anything about the flag that you think it's important for other readers to know; I'd rather you just went ahead and did so instead of setting me riddles.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Setting this particular flag aside, I would probably not leave this kind of thing for mods unless it is a frequent thing and talking with the user on my own didn't help. Mods cannot decide which duplicate is right unless they are experts in that field.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm looking at  your most recent declined flag, which stated: "I think changing the duplicate target to stackoverflow.com/q/1597736/1709587 (which is an exact duplicate with direct, to-the--point answers) would be more useful than leaving closed against the massive reference question that is currently the dupe target. I have to wade through lots of irrelevant stuff to ultimately get to a solution in deceze's answer on the current dupe. (Disclosure: am possibly biased, since I am an author of an answer on the dupe target I'm suggesting.) – Mark Amery Jun 29 at 15:51"

Comment: @Dharman I'm a Python noob, but I can still tell when a question is a dupe of different question. You don't have to be an expert to determine dupes

Comment: In effect as a moderator I tend to look carefully when a close as duplicate benefits the flagger -- if it were me (it wasn't) I may have declined on that reason.  My point is there may be things that taken individually (biased to close/not great dupe reason) may have been 'helpful', but taken together push it over the limit to 'decline'.

Comment: @Dharman You're on point with that; we can't tell unless we're at least familiar in that field.  (After a while, technologies meld to the point where the jargon may differ but the ideas aren't new).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Sure, I agree with you in principle that that could be a reason for declining such a flag. However, we have a clearly-written rejection reason in this case articulating an entirely different reason. The factors you describe were not mentioned in it.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest solution is: Earn a gold badge in that tag, then you can just edit it in yourself. But always remember that curation on SO is a *collaborative* effort, you should always talk to the ones that closed those questions, there might be reasons for their choice.

If you don't have a goldbadge yet, you can still ping the goldbadger that closed it and ask if he could change the dupe. You might also find a goldbadger in the PHP chatroom. However, always remember that time is a limited resource. Focus your effort on questions that are often visited first.

Comment: *"The easiest solution is: Earn a gold badge in that tag"* -- LOL

Answer (score 8):

Most of the points suggested in the other answers are good, but there are two more worth emphasising:

- If the tag also has an active chatroom, you may consider seeking assistance there. You might even find the same gold badge holder who marked the duplicate, or other gold badge owners who may be able to provide their own assessment of the duplicate target. As also advised in the answer to [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364469/1233251), you may also choose to pay a visit at the SOCVR and propose a re-open, although this would most likely be more expensive and less reliable than the former.
- Please do *not* flag for moderator attention unless in very obvious or problematic cases. It has been established that moderators should be involved in matters which they can in fact validate without any expertise in the question's technologies or field. In other words, it's not up to them to validate the accuracy of a duplicate target, just like the accuracy of an answer, as it would be too inefficient and potentially error prone. Their time and effort is better spent if this concern is delegated to the appropriate tag followers and experts.

And of course, considering the merit of a gold badge, it is always worth intervening with an open mind, as the proposed duplicate target could just be fitting from the closer's point of view. As always, seeking to improve the question is the goal; pointing fingers is an anti-goal.

Answer (score 6):

As a Gold-badger who has made a similar mistake myself in the past, my suggestion is: Leave a comment. Tag the gold-badger user, and explain the problem.  For example:

> @flimzy, I think that's the wrong duplicate. Did you mean this one: ...

I may be unusual among gold-badgers (but I doubt it), in that I appreciate being called out when I make a mistake.

Comment: Just a note that the gold-badger's name may not show up in the autocomplete after pressing `@`; commenters need to type the name of the gold-badger (at least the first three characters) manually.

Answer (score -3):

There are three actions you can take, and each depends on the specific circumstances:

If you have the appropriate reputation, edit the duplicate to include the correct canonical duplicate, and if you’re able, remove the incorrect one.

If you can’t do that, you can always vote to re-open and vote to close with the correct reason (this is a lot of work, so I don’t recommend it)

You can also flag for moderator attention (the “other” flag) as to which should be the correct duplicate and why and we will take care of it.