# How can I make this question/answer more relevant it order to make it pop in the close as a duplicate dialog?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer, canonical

There is a question that would be very good duplicate target but I can't make it to show up in "suggested duplicates" dialog often enough to be used as duplicate target. I'm looking for edit suggestions that are essentially "SEO for suggested duplicates".

I spent a considerable effort shaping up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/285587), trying to make it as helpful as possible. Although still a bit rough in wording, I do believe it's an outstanding contribution, that can answer thousands questions and show how to do it properly (means doing no harm at the same time, which, I would say, is a plague of Stack Overflow which gamification rules inspire hasty and short-sighted answers).

I do believe that this answer is how Stack Overflow is meant to be - it is constantly watched, updated, improved and generally kept up with the technology and my experience with questions asked on Stack Overflow.

At the same time there are dozens of other answers, with hundreds of thousands views, which, although being open ended, outdated, too localized or outright harmful, are considered more relevant by both Google and Stack Overflow, and when you search or try to close as a dupe, those answers are show up first. Hence, even people who are closing a question as a dupe, involuntarily promote bad practices and offer less help than it could be.

As a result, we have PHP community stagnated with c.1998 approach, with scripts written into the third decade of XXI century as though it's still XX, let alone that a closure not being helpful at all.

I tried a lot of things to promote my answer, but it doesn't seem to work at all. As long as I use it as a dupe target manually, it works, but otherwise it gets little to no traction.

How can I make this question/answer more relevant it order to make it pop in the close as a duplicate dialog?

Comment: That question has already been seen 20k times. What makes you think it need additional promotion? You can always bounty the question, that would promote the answer as well. It's been done in the past. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266231/what-kind-of-bounty-message-is-acceptable-for-promoting-your-own-answer) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326616/is-it-acceptable-to-use-the-custom-message-on-a-bounty-to-promote-a-specific-ans), for example.

Comment: I thought I made myself clear that it is not the number of views *per se* is my concern. A pity, I failed completely. Looks like people are taking my question from the same gamification standpoint...

Comment: And no, the last thing I want to do is to ruin this post by offering the bounty, that will attract hordes of "reputation"-greedy wannabees with their usual hasty, incompetent and harmful answers. No, thanks, I've seen it too much times already.

Comment: ... or it could motivate someone to write an even better answer.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you only mention your main concern as the last line of your question here, which is an orthogonal concern with the rest of the post. The last line could be the title of the question, and most of the text could be removed, in my opinion.

Comment: Honestly, the reason I downvoted this is because you focus way more on how incompetent you believe other people to be, and not your actual question. This entire thing could do with a significant rewrite, and a large amount of the text should be dropped entirely. You're not making a good case for this... whatever you're trying to argue for at all.

Comment: @Zoe Just likeI said, it never worked before. Or, rather, it worked exactly the opposite. Why it should work the other way this time?

Comment: Bounties have on several occasions brought out good, or better answers. There's always going to be people who answer anything just to get a bit of rep, but that's pretty much the case with any new question nowadays.

Comment: To post something on meta is to *invite* judgment, to invite criticism, and as you're not new to the meta site, not by a long shot, you already know this, should expect this, and should *accept* this, or if not, then perhaps you should remove the question.

Comment: "a new question on Meta is met by people who has nothing to do with the main site but just spend their time judging people asking questions in Meta." That's objectively and demonstrably false. A [recent blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/the-loop-march-2020/) goes into detail about how Meta participants as a group are the most active in curating the main site, and the original statistics they pulled from also show that recent meta users contribute one in 6 answers on the main site. "Nothing to do" doesn't even come close.

Comment: @Zoe I doubt anyone can write a better answer. This answer is outstanding and there's no need to provide more information. The problem is always new users not knowing how to switch the error reporting on and the answer explains perfectly how it should be done and also what to do with that error once you can see it.

Comment: The problem here is not the answer. It is the question. Your answer is good enough and people know about it and use it often. However, finding this question when you are looking for duplicates is often not easy unless you have the link bookmarked. The title is not as catchy as the one for the old `mysql_*` API was. When the question is not tagged with mysqli the system actually suggests the question for the old API as more suitable. Your meta question would be better worded if you were to seek options to improve SEO of that particular question with details and research.

Comment: I have heard people complaining that YCS gave it a title that makes it more difficult to find. We should seek ways to make that question pop up more often in the duplicate and Google search. It is the most important question in the mysqli tag. You are also doing good job closing and pointing other questions to this one. There are still some old questions which should be linked to this new one instead of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2973202?sort=newest

Comment: Another thing is that the issue of mysqli error reporting is asked too often. We can delete a lot of unneeded duplicates, which either promote the use of `die(mysqli_error($conn));` or bring no traffic to this duplicate e.g. are linked to the wrong duplicate target.

Comment: Here are examples of qs in need new dup target: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895021 https://stackoverflow.com/q/15439919 https://stackoverflow.com/q/2077263 https://stackoverflow.com/q/2228430 https://stackoverflow.com/q/18288218 https://stackoverflow.com/q/36468268 https://stackoverflow.com/q/34488765 https://stackoverflow.com/q/20465546 https://stackoverflow.com/q/45559214 https://stackoverflow.com/q/27779215 https://stackoverflow.com/q/51201627 https://stackoverflow.com/q/54963871 https://stackoverflow.com/q/55436889 https://stackoverflow.com/q/49802869 https://stackoverflow.com/q/47504881

Comment: @S.S.Anne This is a really bad approach. There is nothing inherently wrong with people trying to promote their good answers in the right way. The whole reason why we write good answers is to share the knowledge and we want as many people as possible to see them. Driving more traffic to good answers is what must be done, whether you are the author or not.

Comment: @Dharman Seems fair. I'll rethink my approach. Maybe just downvote posts that are asking for upvotes...

Comment: I've yet to see relevant question to popup in "suggested duplicates" dialog for C#... Even when tagged with C# + NRE the famous "C# What is NRE and how to fix it" does not come up... So while I'm supportive of this post in general I don't know if there are enough people paying attention to that dialog at all (I always google/bing for duplicate).

Comment: @DavyM while most people would come to Meta occasionally, there are people who are lurking constantly, being first to meet the new question. Can you understand the difference?

Comment: @Zoe there are no other people with a gold badge for the tag in question. It means there is nobody with the same amount of experience dealing with questions under this tag. It means the chances for a better answer are thin.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there are habitual closevoters - people who are fed up with thousands repetitive questions, but don't care about the actual OP at all. They just hit the first link from the dialog and move on.

Comment: A gold badge has no relevance in terms of experience or ability to give a good answer. People with gold badges can still give completely trash answers, and people with no badges can still give great ones. Badges aren't an indicator of post quality.

Comment: Are we really shifting to another subject in the comment section?

Comment: The problem with the duplicate search dialog is that it only does a search in the **title** field and it has "exact word match" == true. To elaborate on the example from @AlexeiLevenkov this "What is a NullReferenceException" does find that C# question, but "What is a Null Reference Exception" does not. If you want to SEO it, your only option is the title. For a start we could ask SE if a fuzzy title word match would be possible but I don't know if they use SQL to get that duplicate list or Elastic. In the former case it might turn out to be hard to improve quickly on it.

Comment: @Zoe I have a feeling that you are arguing just for sake of it, but I'll give it another try. There are gold badges and gold badges. The one in question is about a specific API. And to get it is not that easy as in some generic tag such as `PHP` or `JavaScript`. Besides, it is not only about experience in the technology I am talking about, but the experience with questions. The ability to have some statistics, to detect patterns. To devise an answer that covers various issues and side effects, based on the number of questions seen.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396321/3404097) (See my comment there & reply by the op.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad somebody asked this question. I have been thinking about the same thing for few months now.

The question you have answered became de facto a canonical for most mysqli problems. I consider it the most important question in that tag, even though you have provided a similar answer to other questions too.

The problem is that this question is not one which naturally comes up when you get one of the cryptic PHP error messages and you paste it into your search engine (e.g Google, Bind, Duck Duck Go). In fact, even searching for it when you know of its existence is not easy.

I propose a few solutions to this problem. They are open to criticism and discussion and I admit my efforts in driving more traffic to this canonical have not been met with significant results.

## Add more SEO keywords to the question.

This is something I have thought about, but I still do not know what we could add to make the question more searchable. Possibly add more of these error messages, which users get when they don't enable mysqli error reporting.

Here are some examples:

[Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given... what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033466/warning-mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-bool-given)

[I keep getting the error message "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given". Can anyone please tell me why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020259/i-keep-getting-the-error-message-mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-my)

[WarningWarning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60813848/warningwarning-mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-bo)

[hi..i have an error in my programming...its showing Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964722/hi-i-have-an-error-in-my-programming-its-showing-warning-mysqli-fetch-array)

This phrase is probably [seen most often](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22expects%20parameter%201%20to%20be%20mysqli_result%2c%20boolean%20given%22&mixed=0):

> ... expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given ...

yet, [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=expects%20parameter%201%20to%20be%20mysqli_result%2C%20boolean%20given&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIE798IE798&oq=expects%20parameter%201%20to%20be%20mysqli_result%2C%20boolean%20given&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.262j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it does not get you the canonical post you should see.

## Hammer as many posts as possible and edit the ones which were incorrectly closed.

I know you are already doing this, but we need to relink the questions which were incorrectly closed.
I have asked a [meta-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389664/what-should-i-do-about-wrong-duplicate-targets-used-by-gold-badge-holders) about it long time ago, but people still use the wrong canonical. Some have argued with me that the wrong one is still helpful, but that is pure nonsense. These two APIs are completely different even if the difference in name is just one letter.

There's way more questions closed as a duplicate of the old API then there is of the new one. We have been telling people for the past 10 years to stop using the old `mysql_*` API, but we can't deny the truth that it was more popular then the new mysqli, which was meant to replace it.

## Clean up! Delete old duplicates and useless questions.

The ludicrous method of checking and **displaying** the error message manually persists among the PHP community for unbeknown to me reasons. If anyone suggests this, I simply downvote such answer. However, there is plenty of questions, which got such an answer and are can be closed and deleted. We do not need to keep the wrong information on the site in such volumes.

Another point is that we can and probably should delete a lot of questions, which asked about the `mysql_*` API. Search engines incorrectly drive traffic there, because of the letter `i` in `mysqli`. The computer systems thing it is a typo and show the more popular results for `mysql_*` API. In hindsight, it was probably a stupid decision to name the new API this way. This API has been deprecated for almost 4 years now and completely removed since 2019. We can keep some small subset of useful questions more historical reasons, but most questions are good to go. **Do we need >1000 duplicates asking how to see errors in `mysql_*` API if no one should be using that API?** These unnecessary duplicates only propagate bad practices and are not helping anyone anymore.

## Retag questions

What I have noticed is that the Stack Overflow duplicate search takes tags into consideration. If the question does not have mysqli tag, it suggests the old `mysql_*` canonical and users pick that one mistakenly. If you add mysqli tag, the system suggests the correct one most of the time.

Adding the mysqli tag to questions which contain the error message "mysqli* expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given..." does help in driving more traffic there.